# How to use awk or sed to format a block style record into a table?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I'm trying to convert a block-style record into a table. The record is the AIX ODM information regarding disks.

```
--------------------------------------------------------
lsattr -El hdisk2 :-

pvid           00f68614bd9b2da20000000000000000 Physical volume identifier       False
q_err          no                 Use QERR bit                     True
q_type         simple             Queue TYPE                       True
queue_depth    16                 Queue DEPTH                      True
reserve_lock   no                 Reserve Device on open           True
reserve_policy single_path        N/A                              True
rw_timeout     40                 READ/WRITE time out value        True
scsi_id        0x71003f           SCSI ID                          False
start_timeout  180                START UNIT time out value        True
ww_name        0x5000097208426d54 FC World Wide Name               False
--------------------------------------------------------
lsattr -El hdisk3 :-

pvid           00f686145f0caa790000000000000000 Physical volume identifier       False
q_err          no                               Use QERR bit                     True
q_type         simple                           Queue TYPE                       True
queue_depth    16                               Queue DEPTH                      True
reserve_lock   no                               Reserve Device on open           True
reserve_policy single_path                      N/A                              True
rw_timeout     40                               READ/WRITE time out value        True
scsi_id        0x71003f                         SCSI ID                          False
start_timeout  180                              START UNIT time out value        True
ww_name        0x5000097208426d54               FC World Wide Name               False
--------------------------------------------------------
```

The desired output is a table to list the pvid, reserve_policy and ww_names like:

```
hdisk2 00f68614bd9b2da20000000000000000 single_path 5000097208426d54
hdisk3 00f686145f0caa790000000000000000 single_path 5000097208426d54
```

How to do it by awk or sed? 
Please help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line gives what you want:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="---+\n";a["pvid"];a["reserve_policy"];a["ww_name"]}{printf "%s",$3;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i in a)printf " %s", $(i+1);print ""}' file
```

better readable version:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="---+\n"
           a["pvid"]
           a["reserve_policy"]
           a["ww_name"]}
{printf "%s",$3
 for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
     if($i in a)printf " %s", $(i+1)
 print ""}' file
```

Comment: WOW, it is awesome. Thank you, Kent. Do you know any in-depth online tutorial about awk? coz I can only find beginner ones.

Comment: @rafa  : be sure to "accept" the answer that solves your problem (meaning this one! ;-) ). As far as awk tutorials, you could do pretty well reading thru Kent's answers for awk here on S.O. Getting advanced experience in any language requires having to solve advanced problems. So keep plugging away. Good luck to all.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html I think it is for both beginners and "post-beginners"

Comment: @Kent , thanks for the help. I have a followed-up question. If ww_name value is empty, how to put an "N/A" to fill the place? This has to be done to ensure each output line alway have the same number of fields. Can it be done by awk?